# Pattern matching on bash for screen shots on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, ls, glob

I'm having a hard time trying to put together a globbing expression to match the screen shot file name patter on macOS.

I've managed to get the following regex to do the job:

`Screen Shot \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} at \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}( \(\d+\))?\.png`

This regex matches:

```
Screen Shot 2017-04-04 at 23.11.22.png
Screen Shot 2017-04-04 at 23.38.40 (2).png
Screen Shot 2017-04-04 at 23.38.40 (12).png
Screen Shot 2017-04-04 at 23.38.40 (12342).png
```

The closest I've got is the following, that matches everything except the screen shots taken at the same second, the ones with the `(number)` inside:

`Screen\ Shot\ [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\ at\ [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].png`

I've started testing `*?\ \([0-9]\).png` and it works but I couldn't join both expressions because once I did, the result is `no such file or directory`

The idea is to create an alias to remove all the screen shots, like:

`alias clrss="cd ~/Desktop | rm -rf Screen\ Shot*.png"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you tried this:

```
alias clrss="cd ~/Desktop | rm -rf Screen\ Shot*.png"
```

that doesn't work because `|` sends the output of one command to the next command, whereas `;` is for separating sequential commands, so `;` works there:

```
alias clrss="cd ~/Desktop ; rm -rf Screen\ Shot*.png"
```

also, the `-r` is for removing directories and their contents, which is useless because there won't be any directories named `Screen Shot*.png`:

```
alias clrss="cd ~/Desktop ; rm -f Screen\ Shot*.png"
```

but that command will leave you on the Desktop, so this is better:

```
alias clrss="rm -f ~/Desktop/Screen\ Shot*.png"
```

but, if you're worried about matching `Screen\ Shot*.png` matching too much, it would make sense to use a somewhat more specific pattern, e.g.:

```
alias clrss="rm -f ~/Desktop/Screen\ Shot\ [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\ at\ [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]*.png"
```

or, if that's still too general, you could use `grep` with your `perl` regular expression and `xargs rm`, like this:

```
alias clrss="find ~/Desktop -name \"Screen Shot *.png\" |
  grep -P 'Screen Shot \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} at \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}( \(\d+\))?\.png' |
  tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -r -0 rm -f"
```

UPDATE from @alcanaia: on MacOS, use `grep -E` instead of `grep -P` and use `xargs -0` instead of `xargs -r -0`.

UPDATE 2 from @alcanaia: here's a better regex; it includes 12h format and an edge case:

```
Screen Shot \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} at \d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}( (AM|PM))?(( (\d)?\(\d+\))| \d)?\.png
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply!

Unfortunately the last command you posted doesn't work, I'm getting:

`usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
xargs: illegal option -- r [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr] [-L number] ...`


I'm not a bash expert but I've noticed some differences in parameters like `--regexp` instead of `-P` so I suspect that we're using different versions of the tools here. Could you enlighten me on this matter?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have GNU grep 3.0 and GNU findutils xargs 4.6.0 from Macports, whereas MacOS defaults are older, crappier versions. I've updated the answer to work with those tools. PS: if you're getting more into command line, you'll be happier in the long run installing Macports (or Homebrew) in order to install newer `bash`, `grep`, `findutils`, `gawk`, and `gsed` (for starters).

Comment: Thanks @webb I've been able to put it together just changing some things: Change the `-P` to `-E` in `grep`; Removed `-r` in `xargs`; Improved the regex to consider some other cases like 12h format and screen shots taken really fast resulting in some extra digits before the `(x).png`, so the new regex is `Screen Shot \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} at \d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}( (AM|PM))?(( (\d)?\(\d+\))| \d)?\.png`